# Pentaho 5 BI Server gwt plugin

Tags: java, gwt, plugins, pentaho

I'm updating a gwt plugin that function properly in BI 3.x-4.x. I made some corrections in code and now the plugin is able to save/load its data in the repository and load its status when i type url in browser

```
http://localhost:8080/pentaho/content/stdashboard?path=/home/admin&action=test2.std&mode=view#dashboard
```

First I note that  action in operations from may content-type don't do anything and i used a perspective referenced later in plugin.xml and plugin.spring.xml.

When run the application the generated url is

```
http://localhost:8080/pentaho/api/repos/:home:admin:test2.std/run?ts=1395256028350
```

and in my ContentGenerator (class i receive the path value as "/home/admin/test2.std" which is ok according to this version but i thing i'm missing or doing something wrong because the GWT-WS is not called, only ContexGenerator.

When I type url in browser the application exec first ContentGenerator, then WS and then again the ConntextGenerator.

plugin.xml

```
<plugin title='STDashboard Pentaho Plugin' loader="OVERRIDING" name="stdashboard">
  <webservice id="olapInteraction" type="gwt" 
      class="com.stratebi.stdashboard.server.OlapInteractionImplLite"/>
  <content-type type="std" mime-type="text/html">
    <title>STDashboard Plugin</title>
    <description>STDashboard configuration file</description>
    <icon-url>content/stdashboard-res/stdashboard_16.jpg</icon-url>
    <meta-provider>com.stratebi.stdashboard.STDashboardContentTypeMetaProvider</meta-provider>
    <operations>
      <operations>
        <operation>
        <id>RUN</id>
        <perspective>run</perspective>
      </operation>
    </operations>
  </content-type>
  <content-generator id="std" title="STDashboard" type="std.run"
      class="com.stratebi.stdashboard.STDashboardContentGenerator"/>
    <static-paths>
      <static-path url="/stdashboard-res" localFolder="resources"/>
    </static-paths>
  <overlays>
    <overlay id="startup.STDashboardPlugin" 
         resourcebundle="content/stdashboard-res/stdashboard">
      <button id="openSTDashboard" label="${stdashboard.tooltip}" 
              command="Home.openFile('STDashboard','STDashboard',
              'content/stdashboard?solution=system&amp;path=temp&amp;action=true');
              $('#btnCreateNew').popover('hide')" />
    </overlay>
    <overlay id="launch" resourcebundle="content/stdashboard-res/stdashboard">
          <button id="stdashboardButton" image="content/stdashboard-res/stdashboard.png"
              command="Home.openFile('STDashboard','STDashboard',
              'content/stdashboard?solution=system&amp;path=temp&amp;action=true')"
              label="${stdashboard.tooltip}" />
        </overlay>
    </overlays>
</plugin>
```

**plugin.spring.xml**

```
<beans "namespaces list...">
  <context:annotation-config />
  <bean id="stdashboard" 
        class="com.stratebi.stdashboard.STDashboardContentGenerator" scope="prototype"/>
  <bean id="stdashboard.run" 
        class="com.stratebi.stdashboard.STDashboardContentGenerator" scope="prototype"/>
</beans>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it helps, but I'd look into exposing functionality via Rest Endpoints using Jersey.

That way you only need to declare your endpoint in plugin.spring.xml and you call them using

```
/pentaho/plugin/<your plugin>/<whatever urls you decide to create>
```

The rule of thumb we use here at webdetails is if you're generating file-based content to show to the user, use the content generator and the `api/repos/...../<run or edit or generatedContent>.`

If you're exposing a service that will be consumed by your plugin, use a REST endpoint with a Jersey  resource.

Comment: Well I understand your answer, but I have no time to rework and I a novice with GWT. I used a work around. I modified the content generator and check the requested URL, and if it contain the resource to load I get it and do a response.sendRedirect to the plugin's URL. It's not standard but worked for now.